# PowerApps - Excel connecivity issue

Tags: powerapps

I don't know why, but when I try to do a search with a cdm dataset it returns all of my data, but not for an excel file. Any idea why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important in PowerApps to understand that it cannot return more than 500 results at a time from a query. After that you can check if the data you are pulling from allows delegation.

link to delegation info:
https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/delegation-overview/

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe it will be fixed "soon". Thanks anyway!